# Transivity / Binary relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, binary

Discuss the Transitivity of Binary Relations

$\mathcal{S} $ $a$ on $\Bbb R $ defined by $a (x, y)$ $\in \Bbb R^2  $--> $x \leq ay$ ( for some a $ \in \Bbb R$ )

I have this assignment about transitivity and binary relation, but i have no idea how can it be related by that formula on top.

Comment: It would help tremendously if you use [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and more standard notation.  I can only imagine your $E$ is meant to be $\in$ and your $R_2$ is meant to be $\Bbb R^2$.  What `Sa` is meant to mean and what $a$ is I'm not entirely sure.  Taking a rather wild stab in the dark, do you mean to say the relation $\mathcal{S}$ defined on $\Bbb R^2$ is given as $x\mathcal{S} y$ iff $\exists a\in \Bbb R$ such that $x\leq ay$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just realize the MathJax notation!

Comment: It is still unclear what is meant.  Is $a$ given ahead of time?  Say for example, $a=3$.  We have $1\sim 2$ since $1\leq 3\cdot 2$.  We also have $2\sim 1$ since $2\leq 3\cdot 1$.  Similarly, we have $4\sim 2$ since $4\leq 3\cdot 2$.  However, despite $4\sim 2$ and $2\sim 1$ we do not have $4\sim 1$ since it is not true that $4\leq 3\cdot 1$.  What about if $0<a<1$?

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure about this notation but suppose that $R$ is the relation such that if $(x,y)\in R$ then $x\leq ay: a,x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let's think about $y\geq \dfrac{x}{a}$. Geometrically, this is interpreted as the region including and above the line $y=x/a$.

So suppose $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z)\in R$. We want to show that $(x,z)\in R$, hence the transitivity of the relation.

If $(x,y)\in R$, then $y\geq\dfrac{x}{a}:a\in \mathbb{R}$ and if $(y,z)\in R$, then $z\geq\dfrac{y}{b}:b\in\mathbb{R}.\quad$

Now, we want to show that $z\geq\dfrac{x}{c}:c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Well, since $z\geq\dfrac{y}{b}$ and $y\geq\dfrac{x}{a}$, then $z\geq\dfrac{x}{ab}$

Since $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $ab\in\mathbb{R}$ and we can replace the product with $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, the relation is transitive.